# Create and Map Home Directory for AD Users using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, home-directory

I used to create and map the home directory for new AD users in Active Directory Users and Computers GUI with following syntax:

\FileServer\users\%username%

This trick automatically creates home directory for user in FileServer and automatically grant full control to user on the directory. I was wondering what could be the PowerShell way of doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think first of all you should get the User.

```
$user = get-ADUser -Filter { Name -like "Mike" }
```

Then create a Folder New-Item, something like:

```
$sac = $user.SamAccountName
$folder = New-Item \\Server\Filesystem\$sac -Type Directory
```

And then you have to set the permissions via [Set-ACL](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849810.aspx)

create new acl object

```
$AclOb = New-Object
System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domain\$sac", 'FullControl', 'ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit', 'None', 'Allow')
```

> The security identifier (domain$sac);The right (FullControl);
> Inheritance settings (ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit) which means to force all folders and files underneath the folder to inherit the permission we’re setting here;
> Propagation settings (None) which is to not interfere with the inheritance settings;
> Type (Allow).

and set-acl

```
Set-Acl -Path $folder.FullName -AclObject $AclOb
```

Greetz Eldo.Ob